# How to replace a product slider on click of a different navigation menu on a web page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navigation

I have a webpage with a slider bar and a navigation bar , the slider move to left and right on the click of two buttons. Now I want to add the functionality when user will click on different navigation menu only the selected product will shown to the user, can someone please help me to do that, I don't have much idea about web development therefore your help is so needed for me

Here I am adding the HTML , CSS and JavaScript code

```js
const productContainers = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slider-container')];
const nxtBtn = [...document.querySelectorAll('.nxt-btn')];
const preBtn = [...document.querySelectorAll('.pre-btn')];
productContainers.forEach((item, i) => {
  let containerDimensions = item.getBoundingClientRect();
  let containerWidth = containerDimensions.width;

  nxtBtn[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    item.scrollLeft += containerWidth;
  })

  preBtn[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    item.scrollLeft -= containerWidth;
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.maincontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(231, 230, 229);
  display: flex;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: rgb(231, 231, 233);
  /* padding: 10px; */
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image img {
  /* width: 410px; */
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 500px; */
  object-fit: cover;
}

.nav-slider {
  width: 70%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(231, 231, 233);
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  background-color: rgb(231, 231, 233);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar li {
  float: left;
}

.navbar h1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: node;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15px;
  color: rgb(119, 113, 113);
}

.navbar ul li a::after {
  content: " ";
  height: 1px;
  width: 0;
  background: #0f0f0f;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 438px;
  /* padding: 5px; */
  position: relative;
  /* border: 1px solid rgb(233, 18, 18); */
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.slider-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.slider-product {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: chartreuse;
  border-radius: 2%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.slider-product::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.slider-image {
  width: 198px;
  height: 47%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  position: relative;
}

.slider-img-details {
  width: 155px;
  height: 155px;
  padding: 17px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info {
  width: 88%;
  height: 50%;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin-left: 11px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.product-name {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  font-family: serif;
  color: #161587;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.brand {
  margin-top: 25px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin-left: 9px;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.stockdetails {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.price {
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 11px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.actual-price {
  margin-left: 7px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.addToCard {
  width: 85%;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 13px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.pre-btn,
.nxt-btn {
  border: none;
  width: 6vw;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #dbd9d9 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 8;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.pre-btn {
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.nxt-btn {
  right: 0;
}

.pre-btn,
.nxt-btn {
  opacity: 0;
}

.pre-btn:hover,
.nxt-btn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="maincontainer">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="7.webp">
  </div>
  <div class="nav-slider">
    <div class="navbar">
      <h1>AMD</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" style="color: black;">FEATURE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">AMD RAYZEN3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">AMD RAYZEN5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">AMD RAYZEN7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">AMD RAYZEN9</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <section class="slider">
      <button class="pre-btn">&#155;</button>
      <button class="nxt-btn">&#155;</button>
      <div class="slider-container">
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-product">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="slider-image.jpg.webp" alt="product" class="slider-img-details">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p class="product-name"><b>AMD Rayzen 3 3200G Processor</b></p>
            <p class="brand"><b>AMD</b></p>

            <p class="stockdetails"><span style="color: #f16a08;">&#10004</span><b>in stock</b>
            </p>
            <p class="price">&#8371 87400</p>
            <p class="actual-price">&#8371 90400</p>
            <button class="addToCard"><b>Add to card</b></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </section>
</div>
</div>
```

I have the different navigation menu like AMD RAYZEN3,AMD RAYZEN5,AMD RAYZEN7,AMD RAYZEN9, I want to implement that on click of navigation menu like AMD RAYZEN3 the product slider will replace the product only with AMD RAYZEN3 product.

Comment: You have some issues in closing your tags in HTML.

Comment: You need to write the code on your own. Research how to: on a button click - show an element ID where that ID is stored inside that button's `data-*` attribute. Hide all the other DIVs wrappers beforehand as well.